# Tap interface is not receiving packets

Tags: linux, tcpdump, interface, tap, scapy

I'm configuring a tap interface and trying to send and receive packets through it, i configure it like this:

```
ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap multi_queue
ip link set tap0 up
```

i'm using scapy to send traffic to the interface, the command is :

```
p = Ether()/IP()
sendp(p, iface = 'tap0')
```

using

```
tcpdump -i tap0 -vvven -vlan
```

and didn't catch any packets.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/822740/tap-interface-is-not-receiving-packets