# Sending data to a Linux tap interface without using sudo

Tags: networking, network-interface

I'm trying to set-up unit tests for my networking scripts. As the unit tests are run by a non-root user ("jenkins", typically), I want to be able to set-up an network interface that can be used by jenkins just to test the packets that are being sent from my networking scripts. The program I'm testing uses the network interface in "promiscuous" mode and, ultimately, is run under the root user as a Linux service. However, I want the functionality unit tested without requiring root login or interactive input - The jenkins "user" is not an interactive user on the system.

I can set-up a tap interface (CentOS 7.x) in the following manner:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user jenkins
sudo ifconfig tap0 promisc up
```

This brings up an interface, which I can see using `ifconfig`, but it is not "RUNNING".

I can send data to it by running my program using `sudo XXXX`, so my program is working as expected. However, if I run the program through the jenkins account, the packets are not going through - I can temporarily switch the jenkins user account to be "interactive" to try this. I'm using Wireshark to view the throughput on this interface.

I've tried this using my own user account, and other accounts, but only the root account works.

I feel there is some command-line invocation I can use to allow a non-root user to utilize a (private, user-owned) network interface, but I can find nothing.

I *could* possibly work out a system using `sudo` and/or suid (`chmod 4755 XXX`) permissions that would allow the unit tests to run with root privileges, but it seems that I should be able to run automated tests without having to go through this somewhat tortuous process.

Does anybody know how I can utilize a tap interface from a user account?

Note: Ultimately, my program uses `libpcap`'s `pcap_inject` to inject a packet into the interface.

Also, I can inject packets as a non-root user onto my real network interface and that works, but it's somewhat dangerous to be letting my packets (which could be erroneous) loose onto the real network. It seem incongruous that a user can utilize a real interface, but not utilize a "tap" interface for testing.

I've looked into network namespaces (amongst other items). AFAIK, this isn't going to help, but I allow for being corrected on this.

This might be a variation on this question, but which has not, sadly, been answered yet: [Tap interface is not receiving packets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332810/tap-interface-is-not-receiving-packets)

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for user and network namespaces, subject to kernel configuration calling `unshare -Urn` will run program (by default the shell) with a private network namespace where virtual network interface can be created as if it is root on a separate machine.